# aggregation inside "case when" - What's the executing order?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, evaluation

Why does this simple query result in a "division by zero" Error?

```
select 
case when b > 0 then sum(a / b) end
from (values (1,1),(2,1),(1,0),(2,0)) t (a,b)
group by b
```

I would expect the output:

| case |
| --- |
| 3 |
| NULL |

The only explanation I have is that postgres calculates the sum before doing the grouping and evaluating the case.

Comment: ¡Good question! Probably PostgreSQL is trying to be smart and it's pre-calculating things before filtering.

Comment: Using `sum(case when b > 0 then a / b end)` instead [does yield the expected result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4aaf283d1f949e18852ef24995d83da0).

Comment: I think it kinda makes sense that `a / b` runs on every row before the aggregation, then the `case of` expression runs only once (per group) after the aggregation on the result of the `sum(…)`. The hypothetical future conditionals don't make a difference to that - what if the condition was `avg(b) > 0`? I don't have enough knowledge of the SQL spec to provide a definitive answer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL):

> […] a `CASE` cannot prevent evaluation of an aggregate expression contained
> within it, because aggregate expressions are computed before other
> expressions in a `SELECT` list or `HAVING` clause are considered. For
> example, the following query can cause a division-by-zero error
> despite seemingly having protected against it:
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN min(employees) > 0
>             THEN avg(expenses / employees)
>        END
> FROM departments;
> ```

So it is expected that aggregate expression `sum(a/b)` are computed before other expressions. This applies not only to Postgresql, but also to Sql Server too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [NULLIF()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to avoid the problem, you don't need a CASE for this:

```
SELECT  
     SUM(a / NULLIF(b,0))
FROM 
    (values (1,1),(2,1),(1,0),(2,0)) t (a,b)
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY 1; -- first (and only) column
```